# between list calculations per row in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Let's say i have the following list of df's (in reality i have many more dfs).

```
seq <- c("12345","67890")

li <- list()

for (i in 1:length(seq)){

  li[[i]] <- list()

  names(li)[i] <- seq[i]

  li[[i]] <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3),
                        B = c(2,4,6))
}
```

What i would like to do is calculate the mean within the same cell position between the lists, keeping the same amount of rows and columns as the original lists. How could i do this? I believe I can use the apply() function, but i am unsure how to do this.

The expected output (not surprising):

```
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 4
3 3 6
```

In reality, the values within each list are not necessarily the same.

Comment: You already have an answer but here it goes: 1) `seq` is a base function, use another name; 2) `li[[i]] <- list()` is not needed, you reassign it later to a df; 3) do `names(li) <- seq` just once after the loop; 4) as a loop control, `seq_along(li)` is better than `1:length()`. In the case `length(li)` is zero you will have the vector `1:0` but with `seq_along` it will not throw an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no `NA`s, then we can `Reduce` to get the sum of observations for each element and divide  by the `length` of the `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, li)/length(li)
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 2 4
#3 3 6
```

If there are `NA` values, then it may be better to use `mean` (which has `na.rm` argument).  For this, we can convert it to `array` and then use `apply`

```
apply(array(unlist(li), dim = c(dim(li[[1]]), length(li))), c(1, 2), mean)
```

---

An equivalent option in `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
reduce(li, `+`)/length(li)
```

Comment: wow, these solutions are surprisingly simple. don't even need to use any apply() function. Thanks!

Comment: @FlyingDutch  Only if there are no NAs as `1 + NA + 5` gives NA